# Convergence of subsequences implies convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. If the subsequences $(x_{kn})$ is convergent for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ then does it say that the original sequence is convergent?

Intutively it feels true.

Firstly we can easily establish that all these subsequences converge to same number say l.

Now, if at all $(x_{n})$ converges, it must converge to l. So we have to show that $x_{n}\rightarrow l$.

Is it possible to prove by just using definition of convergence? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Let $x_{n} = 1$ if $n$ is prime and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: If you include $k=1$ then it’s trivially true; for $k>1$ then consider the sequence $x_n = 1$ if $n$ is prime and $x_n = 0$ otherwise. Any subsequence of the form $x_{nk}$ is the constant zero sequence, yet the sequence clearly doesn’t converge.

Comment: Oh yes! That will help.